# hidden date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts

I want to set a hidden date picker just like hidden text box. Else i want to get the value of text box as date time format

Comment: Not sure I understand. What would a hidden date picker be good for? Why not just use a normal hidden input?

Comment: What do you mean by 'hidden date picker'? The user will need to interact with it some how...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap it into a `<div style="display:none"></div>`, but I don't see the point of doing such a thing/

Comment: I have 6 date picker whose start date and end date depends on the value the value stored in data base. So only if i use date picker I am able to assign start date and end date. If i use hidden text the value gets changed

Answer (score 0):

Try Jquery Ui date picker http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ . Is it what you are looking for ?